# Cookies not getting Saved on Live website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, web-hosting, netlify

I hosted my client side on Netlify and backend on Heroku.
Everything is working fine locally, but as soon as I deployed the changes live it stopped working.

1. Locally in my client side, I have added proxy in `package.json`
   like `"proxy": "localhost:5000"` (Server was running on 5000 port locally) and it is working and I am able to store cookies in Chrome.
2. After deploying to Netlify, I just removed the proxy, the user is getting saved successfully in MongoDB which is live but cookies are not getting saved.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong, since everything is working in local.

Comment: Please provide code that you are using for storing the cookies, and where are you facing the problem. We can give suggestions based on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need a custom domain set for your app.

`herokuapp.com` is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List. This means that in browsers that support the functionality (eg. Firefox, Chrome, Opera), applications in the herokuapp.com domain are prevented from setting cookies for `*.herokuapp.com`.

As per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com

Comment: Do you mean i need a seperate custom domain for heroku instead of the free one that heroku provide

Comment: Correct, if your domain is myapp.herokuapp.com for example you're not allowed to set cookies.

Comment: You are allowed to set cookies, but they have to be set for `myapp.herokuapp.com` opposed to for `herokuapp.com`.